# How to add order confirmation page after billing address page in Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

The default WooCommerce checkout structure is this:

cart->billing address -> checkout

but i need an order confirmation page after the billing address is fill correctly.

So i need this:

cart->billind address->confirm order->checkout.

I found the [woocommerce germanized](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-germanized/) plugin, but it's isn't working wel..

Comment: Why do you want to increase friction to buying something? Checkout should show the items you are buying and completing checkout effectively serves as confirmation.